# Reporting on multi-select pick list or make custom object perhaps?

Tags: reporting, picklist

We're looking to keep track of what hospital departments we're selling into. *Should* seem simple enough, except for the fact that sometimes sales folks will of course sell our product into *multiple* departments at once (ie. on one opp), and we'd like to be able to keep track of what departments we're selling into. I thought I'd come to the quick realization that having a multi-select pick list was the answer, however when I began reporting on them, it quickly became apparent that wasn't the case. As I'm sure y'all are well aware, I was getting reporting values of *every single possible* pick list value combination.

OR & ICU
OR & ED
OR & NICU & ED etc.

Vs. 3 OR, 1 ICU, 2 ED, 1 NICU

What I'm curious about is does anyone have a better way to do reporting vs the above, or would you suggest I make a small custom object of "department", and that can be related to the opp. They'd click "new dept." and could check the boxes of the applicable department(s) to their sale.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.  (Using a custom object.) The only other option I can think of is to add a formula field for each option to the object -- perhaps a boolean that's set to true if the corresponding value is included in the selection...but that seems like more of a pain to maintain.

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld ok so you're suggesting going the custom object route, essentially an object full of check boxes, and run reporting from that.

Answer (score 2):

On second thought...I'd go with the formula field option:

Keep your current multiselect picklist as it is now.

Then add a formula field for each picklist option.  Base your reporting on the value of the formula fields.

Something like this:

Checkbox formula field:

CONTAINS(yourFieldName, "Value1")

Comment: `CONTAINS(yourFieldName, "Value1")` does the same thing.

Comment: Ah.  Good point.  :P   I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Devin -- which way did you wind up going with this?  Were you able to get it working?